# getStatic Path not working for base URL "/" in NextJS

Tags: next.js, prismic.io

I'm using Prismic and NextJS for the first time.

What I'm trying to is make it so when the user goes to the base url for the page localhost:3000/ in dev something will load. /About and /Pricing are working fine the base url doesn't work.

```
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import { SliceZone } from '@prismicio/react'
import * as prismicH from "@prismicio/helpers";


import { createClient,  linkResolver } from '../../prismicio'
import { components } from '../../slices'


interface HomePageProps {
  page: any
}


const HomePage = (props:HomePageProps) => {
  return <SliceZone slices={props.page.data.slices} components={components} />
}

export default HomePage


interface HomePageStaticProps {
  params: any
  previewData:any
}

export async function getStaticProps(props:HomePageStaticProps) {
  console.log("DOES NOT FIRE FOR localhost:3000")
  const client = createClient({ previewData:props.previewData })
  const params = props.params;
  const uid = params?.pagePath?.[params.pagePath.length - 1] || "home";
  const page = await client.getByUID("page", uid);
  return {
    props: {
      page,
    },
  }
}


export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const client = createClient();
  const pages = await client.getAllByType("page");
  const paths =  pages.map((page) => prismicH.asLink(page, linkResolver)) as string[];
  console.log(paths) // [ '/pricing', '/about', '/' ]
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };

}
```

or to simplify it further

[[...pagePath]].tsx fails when going to localhost:3000/ but does not fail on localhost:3000/about or localhost:3000/pricing.

```
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next'

interface HomePageProps {
  page: string
}


const HomePage = (props:HomePageProps) => {
  return <>{props.page}</>
}

export default HomePage


interface HomePageStaticProps {
  params: any
  previewData:any
}

export async function getStaticProps(props:HomePageStaticProps) {
  const params = props.params;
  const uid = params?.pagePath?.[params.pagePath.length - 1] || "home";
  //const page = await client.getByUID("page", uid);
  return {
    props: {
      page:uid,
    },
  }
}


export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const paths = [ '/pricing', '/about', '/' ];
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };

}
```

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#when-does-getstaticprops-run

Comment: please make sure to mark my answer as accepted if it helped you. greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Create-T3-App

https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-app

then

your next.config.mjs will default to this as of Nov 7, 2022

```
const config = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
};
export default config;
```

remove

```
const config = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  //i18n: {
  //  locales: ["en"],
  //  defaultLocale: "en",
  //},
};
export default config;
```

This will make default "/" pathing work, if you require i18n, I'm sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your'e not fetching the right way. In order to to have a clean project I would recommend to use a const var where you can determine between `dev` and `production` enviorenment. To do so you can simply create a file for example: `constants.js` containing the following:

```
export const baseurl = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN // <-- your domain on live
    : "http://localhost:3000"; // localhost on dev
```

Now with this you automatically have `localhost` on your `dev`. Notice that you need `http://` which your'e missing at the moment. Now the next example shows you how to fetch something on your root `/` by entering the following code:

```
import { baseurl } from "../utils/constants"; // <-- importing the constant

// This function gets called at build time on server-side.
// It won't be called on client-side, so you can even do
// direct database queries.
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
  // You can use any data fetching library
  const res = await fetch(`${baseurl}/api/posts`)
  const posts = await res.json()

  // By returning { props: { posts } }, the Blog component
  // will receive `posts` as a prop at build time
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  }
}
```